# Installing with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I use PHP 8.1.2 (cli), and have Windows 10. Installing with composer. For example

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

.. and composer doesn't work:

```
..
> CodeIgniter\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> bash -c "if [ -f admin/setup.sh ]; then bash admin/setup.sh; fi"
Script bash -c "if [ -f admin/setup.sh ]; then bash admin/setup.sh; fi" handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1 (this line is with a red background)
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\...\phpspreadsheet> ls
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Windows uses `\\` as path separator. Try adding file names to quotes.

Comment: Looks like you try to run a Bash script on Windows - that is usually not possible. Also, this does not look related to the package you want to install, but to any other section of your composer.json. Can you share it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?